# How can I update a cell based on a value pygsheets?

Tags: pygsheets

Hi I am trying to update a cell e.g. B4 given that the cell e.g. A4 corresponds to my query. I am using pygsheets library. What I have done thus far was to use `cell_list = wks.find("wednesday")`to determine which cell object is it in, afterwards, I am unable to retrieve the cell id given that cell_list is this:  `[<Cell A2 'wednesday '>]`.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
cell_list = wks.find("wednesday")
cell_address = cell_list[0].label
```

each item in the list is a [cell object](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cell.html).